# iPhone-Simulator Cropper for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Has anyone been able to get iPhone-Simulator Cropper or a similar tool working for the iPad? The [website](http://www.curioustimes.de/iphonesimulatorcropper/) claims that it works with the iPad, but when I try to use it I get an error that the screen is the wrong size.

If not iPhone-Simulator Cropper, is there another tool that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that the simulator for the iPad always had a title bar and so the cropper wouldn't work.  What I discovered was that by switching the primary display from my MBP to my external display(3200x1200), the simulator will then open without any borders or title bar, and the cropper tool will work!  Don't forget to set scale to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: Is it perhaps sensitive to the simulated device orientation?